# Setting the value using reflection - error with casting

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5

I am using the code below to set the values of a class, some values on this class are `string` `decimal` `decimal?` `int?` etc.

I have a list of fields - with its value as a string, .net is throwing the exception below:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
at Surventrix.Domain.Model.Entities.StatisticalData.UpdateStatisticalData(ReportCommit commit, ILogProvider log) in StatisticalData.cs: line 591
at Surventrix.Tests.Stats.StatsTest.CreateStatsFromCommit() in StatsTest.cs: line 32
```

my code is:

```
    public void UpdateStatisticalData(ReportCommit commit, ILogProvider log)
    {
        var fields = commit.CurrentFieldList.ToList();

        var properties = typeof(StatisticalData).GetProperties();

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            log.LogMessage("what my name: {0}", p.Name);
            // If not writable then cannot null it; if not readable then cannot check it's value
            if (!p.CanWrite || !p.CanRead) { continue; }

            var mget = p.GetGetMethod(false);
            var mset = p.GetSetMethod(false);

            // Get and set methods have to be public
            if (mget == null) { continue; }
            if (mset == null) { continue; }


            var val = fields.SingleOrDefault(x => p.Name == x.Name);

            if (val == null) continue;

            //field.value is stored as a string
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val.Value)) continue;

            log.LogMessage("set: {0} ----> {1}", p.Name, val.Value);

            var typedVal = Convert.ChangeType(val.Value, p.PropertyType);

            p.SetValue(this, typedVal, null);
        }

    }
```

Question: how can I fix my code so this exception is not thrown, i dont really understand *why* this exception is being thrown here...

*update - result of log**

```
what my name: StatisticalDataID
what my name: OfficeDistanceFromProperty
what my name: OfficeAddress1
set: OfficeAddress1 ----> North Warwickshire House
what my name: OfficeAddress2
set: OfficeAddress2 ----> 92 Wheat Street
what my name: OfficeAddress3
what my name: OfficeCounty
what my name: OfficeTown
set: OfficeTown ----> Nuneaton
what my name: OfficePostcode
set: OfficePostcode ----> CV11 4BH
what my name: ResidentialInternalFloorArea
what my name: ValuationCalculationSqFtAssumed
what my name: SubjectPropertyAddress1
set: SubjectPropertyAddress1 ----> 323 Stanton road
what my name: SubjectPropertyAddress2
set: SubjectPropertyAddress2 ----> cbvcb
what my name: SubjectPropertyAddress3
set: SubjectPropertyAddress3 ----> vcbc
what my name: SubjectPropertyTown
set: SubjectPropertyTown ----> Coventry
what my name: SubjectPropertyCounty
set: SubjectPropertyCounty ----> bcbvc
what my name: SubjectPropertyPostCode
set: SubjectPropertyPostCode ----> CV1 4HH
what my name: OccupierName
set: OccupierName ----> Mr Peters
what my name: AdvanceAmount
set: AdvanceAmount ----> 0
```

**Update** - I have updated to your code @Jon, I am calling the method like so:

```
            var typedVal = NullableSafeChangeType(val.Value, p.PropertyType);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val.Value))
                p.SetValue(this, typedVal, null);
```

which throws an error at:

```
            _log.LogMessage("error is here ---> {0}", input);
            return input == null || input == "" ? null : Convert.ChangeType(input, underlyingType);
```

The input is any valid string, type(System.String)

Comment: Can you show log results? It would be better to add  p.PropertyType to logging at log.LogMessage("set: {0} ----> {1} with type {2}", p.Name, val.Value, p.PropertyType);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with setting the property, and everything to do with changing the type. Here's a short but complete example demonstrating the problem:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object converted = Convert.ChangeType("10", typeof(int?));
        Console.WriteLine(converted);
    }
}
```

Basically, `Convert.ChangeType` doesn't support `Nullable<T>`. You'll have to handle that yourself. You could write a method which detect that the target type is `Nullable<T>`, and either returns null (if the original string value is null or a reference to an empty string) or the result of converting it to the underlying type.

EDIT: For example (completely untested):

```
static object NullableSafeChangeType(string input, Type type)
{
    Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    if (underlyingType == null) // Non-nullable; convert directly
    {
        return Convert.ChangeType(input, type);
    }
    else
    {
        return input == null || input == "" ? null
            : Convert.ChangeType(input, underlyingType);
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I write the if, ifelse statements? Something like: does not work... if(p.MemberType == typeof(int?))

Comment: @Haroon: Well you want `PropertyType` rather than `MemberType`, and you probably want to use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`.

Comment: thanks, for some reason I am getting the exception `System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: conversionType`

Comment: @Haroon: Without any more information (like which call that is) it's impossible for me to help you any further, I'm afraid. You'll need to be more specific - debug through it yourself and try to work out what's going on.

Comment: @Haroon: I have very little clue what that comment was meant to tell me, but it's not enough to help you further. Please do as much debugging as you can yourself, and then add *details* if you can't fix it.

Comment: thanks for all your help, the error was `if (type == null)` should be `if (underlyingType == null)` in the code above

Comment: @Haroon: Yes, it should. Fixed now. But it's worth understanding that answers are very likely to have small typos like this. It's *always* worth making sure you really understand code in an answer, and if you run into problems, try to diagnose them yourself. (Obviously post the corrections afterwards.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the follow method:

```
    private static T Convert<T>(string input)
    {
        if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
        if (input.Is(typeof(T)))
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException notSupportedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(notSupportedException);
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

Using:

```
                try
                {
                    // If Value is not a string => Convert over Generic Method
                    MethodInfo method = typeof(whereConvertImplemented).GetMethod("Convert", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
                    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);
                    var value = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { propvalue });
                    property.SetValue(this, value, null);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
```

Hope it works for you :)

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

This line

> var typedVal = Convert.ChangeType(val.Value, p.PropertyType);

will not work for nullable types. You have add a special case for property types which are nullable types, and if the value if null or empty, then set the property value to null.